# FooTables plugin (Similiar to DataTables) - How to retrieve column and row data from a server/database

Tags: javascript, php, database, footable

Note: Please also keep in mind I do not know JavaScript and I know only Fundamental PHP.

I've searched high, low, far, & wide. I have even tried to learn some JS to figure out a solution. But I have failed at all ends. This question, surprisingly does not exist on this site. So there is no duplicate question here. Also please do not confuse this question with other questions asking about loading large data sets (a large amount of rows) from a json file. Those questions exist and I already know how to do that.

With the DataTables Plugin this is easy. And there is documentation to show you how to do this exactly. Sadly, this does not exist on the fooTable website.

[Here is the only page that FooTables has that is even close to what I need.](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/ajax.html)
**Break down of Question as it would apply to anyone:**

- The table on the page is using the FooTable Plugin
- There are 10,000 rows of data in a database.
- The website owner needs to connect the database to the table
- The table has pagination. 10 rows per page.
- Only 10 rows should load on page load. Not the entire database of records.
- On page load the table pulls 10 rows from the database and only 10 rows making page speed much faster.

This is essentially what I need.

ANY help on this matter is appreciated I have been at it for 2 weeks with no positive results. Please also keep in mind I do not know JavaScript and I know only Fundamental PHP. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Is this the correct way to do rows.php?

```
<?php 
// rows
$rowData = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'firstName' => $firstName,
    'something' => $something,
    'jobTitle' => $jobTitle,
    'started' => $started,
    'dob' => $dob,
    'status' => $status 
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rowData, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "loading from a JSON file" actually is relevant.

From the page you link, they provide this code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable({
        "columns": $.get('columns.json'),
        "rows": $.get('rows.json')
    });
});
```

This is doing an AJAX request to the server to fetch the data from a JSON file, but it doesn't have to be from a file as long as the server responds with JSON data.

So what you would do instead is `$.get('/columns.php')` to get the column data, and `$.get('/rows.php')` to get the row data. [More on $.get here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Then, inside `columns.php`, you have to make your database calls, pull out your data, structure it the [same as this](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/content/columns.json) and [and this](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/content/rows.json) and then [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it.

Now I know you said you don't know any JS and only a little PHP, but you're going to have to learn some, because I'm not writing all that code for you ;)

---

```
<?php // columns.php
$data = array (
    array (
        'name' => 'id',
        'title' => 'ID',
        'breakpoints' => 'xs sm',
        'type' => 'number',
        'style' =>
            array (
                'width' => 80,
                'maxWidth' => 80,
            ),
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'firstName',
        'title' => 'First Name',
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'lastName',
        'title' => 'Last Name',
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'something',
        'title' => 'Never seen but always around',
        'visible' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'jobTitle',
        'title' => 'Job Title',
        'breakpoints' => 'xs sm',
        'style' =>
            array (
                'maxWidth' => 200,
                'overflow' => 'hidden',
                'textOverflow' => 'ellipsis',
                'wordBreak' => 'keep-all',
                'whiteSpace' => 'nowrap',
            ),
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'started',
        'title' => 'Started On',
        'type' => 'date',
        'breakpoints' => 'xs sm md',
        'formatString' => 'MMM YYYY',
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'dob',
        'title' => 'Date of Birth',
        'type' => 'date',
        'breakpoints' => 'xs sm md',
        'formatString' => 'DD MMM YYYY',
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'status',
        'title' => 'Status',
    ),
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

This is exactly the same as fooTable's [columns.json](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/content/columns.json) example, just in PHP.

Now that it's in PHP, you can pull your data from the database instead of hardcoding. I don't know what your database looks like, so I couldn't write that code for you even if I wanted to.

rows.php will look pretty much the same, just a different array format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok so this is exactly how I currently have my table set up. Just without your $.get('/columns.php')  and $.get('/rows.php') I'm pulling it from the json files but want to pull from the server instead. I will read the links you provided to see if I can understand tem and how to implement this. Will get back to you. please reply that you have received my response. Thanks again. In your reply is there any advice you can give for setting this up with php?

Comment: Yeah I do not know enough php and JS to be able to to this. I understand the concept but I am at a total loss. Looks like all this work has been for nothing. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: IS there anyway you can show me what it will look like once finished? In the example you can use just 3 columns and a few rows and from there i can edit it to how I need it to work? I will pay you if you want i don't have much but I really need this done.

Comment: @DanielMorris No problem. Maybe someone else on your team who wrote the backend + database can help?

Comment: Thank you! And I've written it all. But It's been tedious and some luck involved and a lot of googling.

Comment: @DanielMorris Added a snippet to me answer.

Comment: Ok so when I view your columns.php file in the browser in outputs the same json file. That I understand. Also Thank you for writing it. I can write the connection to the database. Once I am connected I am confused as to how to make all of this work together. For example: The rows.php file. I can replicate what you did but would I not just be using php to display the same json file that already has my data in it? That's what you did with columns.php you just used php to output the same data. This is where I get even more confused. But I can connect to my database.  Let's say.....

Comment: I can even (maybe) replicate your columns.php and write the rows.php file. I should only have to write like one array? (and it will loop through all the data or something?) And rather than putting the actual values (like first name, DOB, last name, etc,.) I would need to put a variable of some sort? I want to cry right now. I really thought I could make this site. So much work done to it and this one thing is the ONLY thing standing in my way. Am I close at all?

Comment: Is this right? <?php 
// rows
$rowData = array(
 'id' => $id,
 'firstName' => $firstName,
 'something' => $something,
 'jobTitle' => $jobTitle,
 'started' => $started,
 'dob' => $dob,
 'status' => $status 
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rowData, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

Comment: Added to main OPost

Comment: Ah... you're right. I left some details out. FooTables should provide you some details about what page number it wants you to return and how many records it wants. This is what DataTables does... let me see if I can find where it says that.

Comment: @DanielMorris I can't find where in the docs it talks about giving you a page number or anything. DataTables sends you what columns it expects, which column to sort on, the current page number, the number of rows it expects... all kinds of stuff you can use in your SQL query. It doesn't look like FooTables provides any of that, which means you're just supposed to give it a whack of data and it does pagination and sorting client-side, which is awful for performance.

Comment: @DanielMorris If it were up to me, I'd drop FooTables, replace it with DataTables and style it to look the same. Pretty sure DataTables has all the features FooTables has and more. I think you're SOL with FooTables; doesn't look like it can do what you want.

Comment: yeah casue this is what I got and it's prolly way off i'm playing guessing games here. http://i.imgur.com/2pEkwMd.png

Comment: at least with datatables I've had that working before and pulling from the database with ajax.

Comment: Looks like you're only returning a single row. You'd need to push each row into an array and return 20 of them, or however many are on a page.

Comment: love DataTables, It's just missing some of the feature FooTables has and I have NO idea how to style DataTabales. But  iguess learning to syle datatables will be 1,000X easier than learning how to do what im trying now. t least styling Datatables is something I know i can learn with time.

Comment: Thanks for all your help man. You stuck with me longer than most have on here.

Comment: @DanielMorris What features does FooTables have that DataTables doesn't? I've been using DataTables for awhile now; everything I've wanted is already be built in.

Comment: @DanielMorris Here, I did 90% of the styling for you: https://jsbin.com/bipaza/6/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Also, I got server side processing working with FooTable. I figured it out with the help of a friend. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0cc0b6816aa45adc54b5fc2bd9b50f84

Comment: @DanielMorris That's good, but it's not paginated. You're returning every row from the database all at once. It won't scale very well once you get a huge number of records.

Comment: It's the EXACT same as the .json file. The .json file lists 10,000 rows of data in json form. The PHP is simply written in a way that it pulls the exact same rows from the database and formats them in the exact same way. so if you were to view the rows.json and rows.php they are identical in code. rows.json simply holds the data. It's not responsible for the pagination. It just holds the large rows  of data. The javascript elsse where paginates it. And when you view source doe you only see 10 rows at a time. and judging by page speed it loads instantly. you can tell it paginating

Comment: @DanielMorris Right. It's paginated in JS. If 10K rows is still perfomant, then there's no problem. What you have to keep in mind though is that the user is downloading 10K rows of data that they might never look at, your MySQL database is fetching 10K rows, those 10K are held in the browser's memory, and whenever you search or sort, the user's computer is doing the heavy lifting. All of that can be avoided if you do it server-side.

Comment: Where and how is it loading these 10,000 rows on page load. The FooTables Plugin is using data-paging to take care of the performance increase by limiting the number of rows that need to be drawn when the plugin initializes. The rows.php/.json might have a million rows but it's only loading and drawing the ones that the script is working with. based on the script itself, breakpoint changes, or the window resizes. It's asynchronously loading the data into the page. If i'm wrong about this and im not saying that im not please tell me how i am wrong explain it to me please. I need to understand!!

Comment: @DanielMorris You are correct that it's only **drawing** 20 at a time or so, and that is indeed the biggest bottle neck when it comes to updating the DOM. However, the remaining 9980 rows are still in memory, in your browser. It is **not** asynchronously **[down]loading** additional data as its needed -- it's all fetched, all at once.

Comment: @DanielMorris: We can verify this is true by opening Chrome Dev Tools and going to Network/XHR: http://imgur.com/IZAkxY8 and http://imgur.com/AjWMutX

Comment: Ahhhh yes I see. I'm looking at it now on Firebug too. Gonna do some more research or in the end use your styling and switcing to datatables which i already know how to use. Just not what i wanted for this particular project. missing a few things. always pros and cons tho.